# Split with comma not followed with a lowercase letter

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regex-lookarounds

Help me with pattern please. I have string with commas like:

```
12v some, Item, which contains comma, Another item
```

I need to split it by commas and get:

```
 0 => '12v some'
 1 => 'Item, which contains comma'
 2 => 'Another item'
```

how to use rule if there are letter in lowercase after comma dont split str?

I'm using [\s,][ ][A-Z0-9]+, but it trim some text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a lookahead based solution like

```
preg_split('~\s*,(?!\s*\p{Ll})\s*~', $s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RdlNwb/2)

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `,` -  a comma
- `(?!\s*\p{Ll})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`) followed with a Unicode lowercase letter (`\p{Ll}`)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/8yRYec):

```
$s = "12v some, Item, which contains comma, Another item";
$res = preg_split('~\s*,(?!\s*\p{Ll})\s*~', $s);
print_r($res);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12v some
    [1] => Item, which contains comma
    [2] => Another item
)
```